# refresh a view in iphone programming

Tags: iphone

i want to refresh my current view when i click a button 
how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[yourView setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: the compiler is showing warning that this class may not respond to +setNeedsDisplay...

Comment: You need to send setNeedsDisplay to a concrete instance of a view not to UIView (the class).

Comment: if you're trying to send this message to UIViewController, you indeed will get the warning. If you want to refresh  the view, that is associated with a certain view controller, you should call this message as following: [self.view setNeedsDisplay].